# a single " appearing in a persons name is throwing off a load from my ssis package

Tags: csv, ssis, delimiter

Everything was working fine but recently names have been showing up in the data as follows:

John Smith"

The problem with this is the source file is a csv and is already comma delimited and I'm also already using " as a text qualifier because I do have a field for company name that does include a comma.  For example:

"Acme roadhouse, llc"  - and the text qualifier is keeping all of that in one cell even with the comma.

Any help would be very much appreciated and if you need more information, please let me know.

I have tried changing the text qualifier and I have also messed around with the delimiter.  The problem is, I have no control over the source file that is being fed to me.  I believe this keeps happening from human error, so if I cant get the data entry people to fix this on their end, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: When I have unreliable source data, I usually end up writing some sort of ultra defensive preprocessing step that takes the original file and makes a standard compliant CSV out of it. That way I have the original, the translated and then the data in the database. Whether you do it all in an SSIS package, custom exe that runs before the package kicks off, etc is usually driven by what you/the support team can handle

Comment: Thank you for that info.  I will try going that route.